# Dynamically Naming Class Instances in Java

Tags: java, loops, button, controls

I'm trying to use a foreach loop to create a button for everything in a list:

```
List<String> aList= new ArrayList<>();
```

And then using a foreach loop;

```
for(String aString: aList){
    // Some code here to dynamically name buttons with the string 'aString';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names must be determined at compile time,and therefore cannot be dynamic object names.

If you want to be able to give your Button names, you can use Hashmap

```
Map<String, Button> map = new HashMap<>();
//Add objects to the map like this (e.g):

for(String aString:aList){
map.put(aString, new Button());
}
```

and retrieve objects like this:

```
Button mc = map.get(name);
```

if you are just trying to add buttons to a frame then Try the following code :

```
    for(int i=0; i<aList.size(); i++){
            Button temp = new Button();
            temp.setName(aList.get(i));
            temp.setLabel(aList.get(i));
        //write logic to add to frame/panel
        }
```

or

```
  for(String aString:aList){
            Button tempButton = new Button();
            tempButton.setLabel(aString);
            tempButton.setName(aString);
            //write logic to add to frame/panel

        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a reason for not using the foreach syntax? Or just preference?